# Create a dynamic filter with `dplyr` and `dbplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

Let's say I have a list of filters that I want to apply to an SQL table using `dplyr` + `dbplyr`:

```
filters = list(gear = c(4, 5), cyl=c(6, 8))
mtcars_postgres <- dbplyr::tbl_lazy(mtcars, con = dbplyr::simulate_postgres())
```

I want to write a `dplyr::filter` expression that will dynamically create a filter that corresponds to `dplyr::filter(mtcars, gear %in% c(4, 5) & cyl %in% c(6, 8))`. This would correspond to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `df`
WHERE `gear` IN (4.0, 5.0) AND `cyl` IN (6.0, 8.0)
```

The main tools I need here seem to be `dplyr::if_all` and `dplyr::all_of`:

```
mtcars_postgres |> 
    dplyr::filter(
        dplyr::if_all(
            dplyr::all_of(names(filters)),
            ~ .x %in% filters[[dplyr::cur_column()]]
        )
    ) |>
    dplyr::show_query()
```

```sql
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `df`
WHERE (`gear` IN `filters`.`gear` AND `cyl` IN `filters`.`cyl`)
```

This of course doesn't work because `filters` is an env variable, not a data variable. So I try embracing `filters`:

```
mtcars_postgres |> 
    dplyr::filter(
        dplyr::if_all(
            dplyr::all_of(names(filters)),
            ~ .x %in% {{filters}}[[dplyr::cur_column()]]
        )
    ) |>
    dplyr::show_query()
```

```sql
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `df`
WHERE (`gear` IN ((4.0, 5.0) AS `gear`, (6.0, 8.0) AS `cyl`).`gear` AND `cyl` IN ((4.0, 5.0) AS `gear`, (6.0, 8.0) AS `cyl`).`cyl`)
```

This is better, but it seems to put the entire filters list into SQL variables. This is okay, but I'm worried about the duplication of the data, especially if I was dealing with much more data.

To get my ideal result above, I would have to find a way to force `dbplyr` to evaluate `filters[[dplyr::cur_column()]]` in a context where `filters` is defined, `dplyr::cur_column()` works correctly, but without `dbplyr` trying to convert the entire function into SQL as it currently does.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The most general way I know to do this works with both dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
data(mtcars)

ccond = quos(gear == 4, wt > 3)

mtcars %>%
  dplyr::filter(!!!ccond)
```

And with and dbplyr:

```r
library(dbplyr)

mtcars_postgres <- dbplyr::tbl_lazy(mtcars, con = dbplyr::simulate_postgres())

mtcars_postgres %>%
  dplyr::filter(!!!ccond)
```

With the following SQL translation:

```sql
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `df`
WHERE (`gear` = 4.0) AND (`wt` > 3.0)
```

The idea is to make a list of quosures, that contain the conditions. The whole list can be then passed into `filter` where it is spliced by `!!!`.

Some of these functions may be unfamiliar, both `quos` and `!!!` are from the rlang package. These are the plural versions of `quo` and `!!`.

If you want the help file for `!!!` you will likely need to call `` ?`!!!` `` . If R gets confused with these functions and `!` (not) three times, then you can call these as  `` `!!!`(...) ``.

#### Edit

If your conditions arrive as a list, there are several ways to convert these to quosures:

```r
# (1) iteration to convert to a list of quosures
ccond = list()

for(ii in names(filters)){
  qq = quo(!!sym(ii) %in% filters[[!!ii]])
  ccond = append(ccond, qq)
}

# (2) equivalent to above, but more compact
ccond = lapply(names(filters), function(nn){ quo(!!sym(nn) %in% filters[[!!nn]]) })

# (3) as per the comment by @Migwell
filters = list(gear = c(4, 5), cyl=c(6, 8))

ccond = filters %>%
  purrr::imap(
    function(slice, name){ 
      colname <- rlang::sym(name);
      rlang::quo({{colname}} %in% slice)
    }
  ) %>%
  purrr::set_names(NULL)
```

Some of these functions may be unfamiliar, `!!` is the singular version of `!!!` and `sym` turns its contents into a name/symbol. So if `var = "colname"` then `sym(var) == colname`.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks! This pointed me in the right direction of just forming the filter expressions beforehand using `rlang`. However, in my case the filters are provided as a list, which is out of my control, so I can't simply change `list` to `quos`. I had to     `filters |> purrr::imap(function(slice, name){ colname <- rlang::sym(name);             rlang::quo({{colname}} %in% slice)}) |> purrr::set_names(NULL)` to convert the list into a list of quosures which I could then `!!!` as you suggested.

Comment: If you could change your answer to explain how to convert an existing list to a list of quosures, using the filters I described (the use of `%in%` is important), then I'm happy to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need to use dplyr for that.

Here you have a function that returns the sql command based on the input of the filters you need.

```
filters = list(gear = c(4, 5), cyl=c(6, 8))
dfname <- "df"

sqlcommand <- function(filters, dfname) {
  filter.string <- gsub('c(','(',paste(names(filters[1]), "IN", filters[1]), fixed=TRUE)
  if (length(filters)>1) {
    for (i in 2:length(filters)) {
      filter.string <- paste(filter.string, "AND",  gsub('c(','(',paste(names(filters[i]), "IN", filters[i]), fixed=TRUE))
    }
  }
  filter.string <- paste ("SELECT * FROM ",dfname,
                          " WHERE ", filter.string, sep = "")
  return(filter.string)
}

sqlcommand(filters, dfname)

[1] "SELECT * FROM df WHERE gear IN (4, 5) AND cyl IN (6, 8)"
```

You can change the input:

```
filters = list(gear = c(4, 5, 6), cyl=c(4, 6, 8))
dfname <- "df"

sqlcommand(filters, dfname)

[1] "SELECT * FROM df WHERE gear IN (4, 5, 6) AND cyl IN (4, 6, 8)"
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing that, but I feel using manual string interpolation has a lot of disadvantages: difficulties with special characters or SQL keywords in the filters, lack of portability to different SQL dialects, and much higher code complexity are some reasons.